# In Google Scripts, how can I get the month of every cell in a column?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, referenceerror

I am new to Google Scripts.  I have a spreadsheet with a list of dates in column A, and I want the script to loop through this column and put any month that meets a certain specification - say, any month that is between 5 and 10 - in a variable.

Here's my current code:

```
function CalculateInterest(values) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var date_column = sheet.getRange("A3:A");

  var current_cell_date = 0;
  var current_cell_month = 0;

  for (var x = 3; x < 100; x++) {
    current_cell_date = date_column.getCell(x, 1);
    current_cell_month = month(current_cell_date);
  }

  return current_cell_month;
}
```

Right now, I am stuck on simply getting the month number from the date of cell **x**1.  (**x** being the **for** variable.)  My spreadsheet says: *ReferenceError: "month" is not defined. (line 12).*

If I can successfully retrieve the month number from any given cell in this loop, then I know I can compare that number in an **IF** statement.  For example, I can make a variable that contains the number of months that met my specification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
function CalculateInterest(values) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var date_column = sheet.getRange(3,1,sheet.getLastRow()-2).getValues();

  for(var i=0;i<date_column.length;i++){
    var currentDate =  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date_column[i][0]), "GMT", "MM");
    Logger.log(currentDate);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that gets the month between April and November non inclusive for dates in column 1 and puts the month number for those dates in column 2.

```
  function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet13');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var vals=rng.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vals.length;i++)
  {
    if(new Date(vals[i][0]).getMonth()>4 && new Date(vals[i][0]).getMonth()<9)
    {
      vals[i][1]=new Date(vals[i][0]).getMonth()+1;
    }
  }
  rng.setValues(vals);
}
```

Here's my spreadsheet after running.

[image]